# Wordpress Polylang adding pll_e breaks HTML

Tags: html, wordpress, polylang

i'm using polylang to translate my blog site along with loco translate. i'm manually adding string translations which was working fine with get_theme_mod parts, but there is a place that i want to also add custom string translation, after i add manually it breaks html and css won't work then.

it should be seen like this after adding custom string translation ; [works fine without pll_e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sB6GB.jpg)

but after i add pll_e to the that part in index.html ;

```html
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="content">
    
    <?php if ( get_theme_mod('heading-enable','on') == 'on' ) : ?>
      <?php echo get_template_part(pll_e ('inc/page-title') ); ?>
    
    <?php endif; ?>
```

it breaks the html but translation works. its seen like this ; [looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZA7JU.jpg)

does anyone knows the solution ? i think its about get_template_part and get_theme_mod because the same things that i've done with get_theme_mod parts works fine.

by the way there is difference like this with pll_e and without it.

[without pll_e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fwJ6R.jpg)
[with pll_e](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c67np.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

i solved the problem by editing index.html like this ;

```
<div class="content">

<div class="page-title group">
<div class="page-title-inner group">

                <?php if ( get_theme_mod('heading-enable','on') == 'on' ) : ?>
    <h2> <?php echo get_template_part(pll_e('inc/page-title') ); ?>  </h2>

<?php endif; ?>
    
                            
</div><!--/.page-title-inner-->
```